# What counts as a projectile?

Tags: titanfall

The vortex shield is a Titan tactical ability, that "catches incoming projectiles, and projects them back". For the purposes of the vortex shield, what counts as a projectile or not, i.e. Is the charge rifle a projectile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge rifle shoots a beam of energy so there isn't a projectile. A projectile is a physical object which is projected.

I'll update my answer as best I can to make it helpful.

Vortex Sheild stops

- XO-16 Chaingun
- 40mm Cannon
- Quad Rocket
- Triple Threat (Not sure if it stops mines before they land if they hit the shield)
- Sidewinder
- Archer Heavy Rocket
- Mag Launcher (Assuming the grenades hit the shield)

Vortex Sheild does not stop

- Arc Cannon
- Plasma Railgun
- Charge Rifle

Refs,
http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Vortex_Shield
http://guides.cheatcc.com/titanfall-guide-walkthrough/guide_sections/pilot-anti-titan-weapons
http://titanfall.gamepedia.com/Vortex_Shield

Comment: I'm looking for a bit more information; what about other weapons?

Comment: This answer looks like you're speculating; please be careful with speculations.

Comment: Oh it is, but then the question didn't ask to list every weapon which is caught by the shield and ones which are not. It would need testing. My answer started as a comment, but was too long.

Comment: it also stops all infantry weapons and grenades(although their fuses are still live)

Comment: Plasma Railgun shots is also catched.